# java rabbitmq header properties sequence

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am new to java and implemented a rabbitmq application which includes the consumer and producer. I am trying to submit message properties within the header and found an example of how to do this. All works fine except that when the consumer receives the message the properties are not in the sequence it was submitted. Why and how is this changed? Is it because of the key-value pair and does not allow ordering to be set?

Here is my code for the producer message header settings:

```
                AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder builder =   
                     new AMQP.BasicProperties().builder();
                 Map<String,Object> headerMap = 
                  new HashMap<String, Object>();
                 headerMap.put("ID", pId);
                 headerMap.put("threadID",threadID);
                 headerMap.put("fetchDate", ftchdte);
                 headerMap.put("pubDate", pbdte);
                 headerMap.put("query",searchQ);
                 headerMap.put("messageType","POST");
                 headerMap.put("page",origPage);
                 builder.headers(headerMap);
                pchannel.basicPublish("",outputQueueII,builder.build(),
                post.getBytes());
```

Comment: why do you need to keep the order of the headers? There's no implicit order there.

Comment: the reason was that the receiving process expects the headers in a certain format to read the values into appropriate variables.